# An Image Compression tool for windows similar to ImageOptim (of mac)

Tags: windows, image, png, jpeg, image-compression

I was looking for a image compression tool for windows(Windows 7, more specifically), similar to ImageOptim (of mac). I've used few jpeg compressors tools in windows but they aren't giving the desired result. Yes, they compress the size but the quality of JPEGs are not good. some tools always print their water-marks on the image. this is not what I want.

The Tool should have these following features.
1. Free to use Licence.
2. Best Compression
3. Best quality
4. Multiple format compression, eg. JPG, GIF, PNG, etc.
5. Have windows context menu command to directly convert the image right from the explorer.

Waiting for your Replies. Thank You Guys.

Comment: This question is offtopic here (see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)). I have requested that it is moved to Superuser instead.

Comment: if it is not appropiate question to ask then, what should I do now. Please advise.

Comment: You don't have to do anything at this point. The question has been flagged that it needs moderator attention. A moderator will look into this as soon as possible and initiate migration if appropriate.

Comment: I've added a list of alternatives to the website: https://imageoptim.com/versions.html

Answer (score 13):

There's FileOptimizer

http://nikkhokkho.sourceforge.net/static.php?page=FileOptimizer

According to this article it performed the best and the article also lists more options to explore:
http://www.netmagazine.com/features/best-image-compression-tools